# how can I use multithreading on a server program to connect and send data to browser when I'm requesting from the browser?

Tags: c, multithreading

I am trying to use Multithreading in my server program in such a way that when i get request from browser my server should open a txt file and send it to browser to display.
   what I need to do is to have a separate function which does the send/receive inside my main every time there is a request from the browser(client) such as: 127.0.0.1:3490/index.txt
I managed to do it for one request only with my main function but I have trouble with putting every thing in my thread function and send it to browser.

I will appreciate any help
the following is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <winsock.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#define NUM_THREADS 10
#define MYPORT 3490
void *PrintData(void *thread);  
int main() {
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET s;
    unsigned fd;
    struct sockaddr_in my_addr;
  WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(1, 1), &wsaData);
  my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  my_addr.sin_port = htons(MYPORT);
  my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  memset(my_addr.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof(my_addr.sin_zero) );

  s=socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if(s<0) printf("socket failed\n");
  if ( (bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&my_addr, sizeof(my_addr)) ) !=0){ printf("Bind failed!\n");}
  listen(s,10);

    while(1) {
        fd=accept(s,NULL,NULL);
         printf("Client connected\r\n");
        CreateThread(NULL,(DWORD)NULL,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)PrintData,(void*)fd,(DWORD)NULL,NULL);  // creating threads
    }
    closesocket(fd);    
    WSACleanup();
}

void *PrintData(void *thread){
   char *header="HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n";
    char data[512];
    char filename[256];
    FILE *f; 
    printf("It's me, thread!\n");
    SOCKET curr_client = (SOCKET)thread;
    int res;
    while(1){
        res=recv(curr_client,data,512,0);              
        ///data[res]=0;                         
        Sleep(10);
        if(res == 0) printf("error: res == 0");

        sscanf(data,"GET /%s ",filename);  
        printf("Get: %s %d\n", filename, res);
        send(curr_client,header,strlen(header),0);  
        f=fopen(filename,"rb");            
        if(f == NULL){ fputs("Can not find the file!", stderr); }
        while(!feof(f)){
            printf("heloooo");
            int retVal = fread(data, 1, sizeof(data), f);
            ///printf("data is : %s\n", data);
            send(curr_client, data, sizeof(data), 0); 
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
    ExitThread((DWORD)NULL);
}
```

Comment: I've figured it out how to fix the problem that I had in the above question, just in case someone else might have same question, I will put my solution here

Answer (score 0):

First, do not close `fd` in the main function. As it is now you will not close it at all since the loop is infinite, and that means you have a *resource leak*. The last thing you do in in the thread function is to call `closesocket(curr_client);`.

Second, in the thread you loop forever, and never break out of the loop. When there is either an error reading the file, you reach the end of the file, or have an error when receiving/sending from/to the socket, you should break out of the infinite loop. This is following the HTTP specification, that a server should close the connection after each request.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I've changed my code to all the things that you mentioned, but I still have problems running the program. it doesn't send my data to the client(browser) and the browser goes on waiting state but doesn't display anything.

It would be great if someone could fix my code in a way that my send function work properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(1) {
fd=accept(s,NULL,NULL);             
n=recv(fd,data,512,0);              
data[n]=0;                        
sscanf(data,"GET /%s ",filename);  
printf("Get: %s %d\n", filename, n);      
send(fd,header,strlen(header),0);  
f=fopen(filename,"rb");             
if(f == NULL){ fputs("file error", stderr); } 
fread(data, 1, sizeof(data), f); 
returnVal = send(fd, data, strlen(data), 0); 
if(returnVal<0) printf("Your tester failes!\n\n"); 
fclose(f);
closesocket(fd);                   
}
```